# Illustrator CS4 is crashing on startup on OS X 10.7 (Lion). What can I do to fix it?

Tags: crash, osx-lion, adobe-illustrator

When I start Illustrator and click on the toolbar or Create New Print Document, I get the spinning beach ball and have to force quit Illustrator. I already tried cleaning out my preferences directory. What else can I do?

I'm running Illustrator CS4 on Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion).

Comment: I've had some success with moving "~/Application Data/Adobe" to another directory. (Moving it rather than deleting it because space is cheap.)